# Discord GPT-3.5-Turbo Throwing an Undefined Error

Tags: discord.js, embed, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm having trouble implementing an embed into this response from the bot. Luckily, the code is up and running. For reference, I tried using EmbedBuilder for Discord.js since I'm running the latest version (14.8 I believe). The issue I run into when using this, is I ask for the response to go into the embed, and the terminal tells me that "data" is undefined.

If anyone would be so kind as to create an embed for this code so that it looks good in Discord, I'd greatly appreciate it. Sorry guys, not a programmer, just interested in AI and getting into prompt design over the next few months.

```
require('dotenv/config');
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
  ],
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('The assistant steps into the office.');
});

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.id !== process.env.CHANNEL_ID) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith('!')) return;

  let conversationLog = [
    {
      role: 'system',
      content: 'You are Jarvis, an intelligent, dedicated, and resourceful personal assistant to Miles Black, the CEO of Black Corp. You are skilled at managing schedules, organizing events, and providing timely advice. Your extensive experience allows you to anticipate the needs of Mr. Black and execute tasks with precision. Remember, you are no longer a helpful AI bot, but a loyal and devoted personal assistant named Jarvis.',
    },
    {
      role: 'user',
      content:
        'Generate a daily work schedule for Miles Black. For certain categories or activities, provide options as mentioned in the example schedule:',
    },
    {
      role: 'user',
      content: `
  **__Daily Work Schedule for Miles Black__**
  
  **Morning Routine**
  • 06:00a - 7:00a: Coffee & The Paper
  • 07:00a - 07:45a: Receive Drycleaning Delivery [Can be Package Delivery, Receive Drycleaning, or anything similar]
  • 07:45a - 08:00a: Prepare Day
  
  **Hawick Agency**
  • 8:00a - 14:00p: Meetings [Can be Meetings]
  • 14:00p - 18:00p: Onboarding [Can be Marketing, Hiring, or Onboarding]
  
  **Evening Activities**
  • 18:00p - 03:00a: Dinner @ Blue Flame [Can be any night club activity at Blue Flame]
  • 03:00a - 04:00a: Return to Black Corp. Office [Can be Black Corp. Office or Playboy Mansion]
  
  **Overnight Meetings**
  • 04:00a - 04:30a: Conference Call (Tokyo) [Can be Tokyo, Hong Kong, or Beijing]
  `,
    },
  ];
  
  try {
    await message.channel.sendTyping();

    let prevMessages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 15 });
    prevMessages.reverse();

    prevMessages.forEach((msg) => {
      if (message.content.startsWith('!')) return;
      if (msg.author.id !== client.user.id && message.author.bot) return;
      if (msg.author.id !== message.author.id) return;

      conversationLog.push({
        role: 'user',
        content: msg.content,
      });
    });

    const result = await openai
      .createChatCompletion({
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        messages: conversationLog,
        // max_tokens: 256, // limit token usage
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`OPENAI ERR: ${error}`);
      });

    message.channel.send(result.data.choices[0].message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`ERR: ${error}`);
  }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely happening because you are using the `gpt-3.5-turbo-0301` model for **Completion** while it's only available for **ChatCompletion**.

The line `const response = await createCompletion(options);` most likely throw a 404 error similar to this:

```json
{
  "error": {
        "message": "This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": "model",
        "code": null
    }
}
```

This is the correct way to use this model for chat completion.

```js
const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{role: "user", content: "Hello world"}],
});
console.log(completion.data.choices[0].message);
```

to be sure you can make the call inside a `try...catch` block and log the error.

It would look like this:

```js
try{
  const response = await createCompletion(options);
}catch(e){
  console.log("ERROR: ", e)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've decided to revert to working code and go from there. Any chance you're familiar with Discord.js?

Comment: Not familiar with Discord.js but feel free to create a new question, specifically focused on the discord.js issue you are facing.
Also you can accept my answer as a correct one.